# ¿Cúal es la diferencia entre List y ArrayList en .NET?

Tags: c#, vb.net, .net

Hace poco respondi la pregunta de [¿Cómo agregar elementos a un array en C#?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/98036/como-agregar-elementos-a-un-array-de-una-clase) y mientas proponia la solución alternativa que era usar la clase `List`, me recorde que tambien hay una clase llamada `ArrayList`.

Al comparar la documentación de [ArrayList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.collections.arraylist(v=vs.110).aspx) y [List](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx), en algunas partes de estos articulos dice:

> "La clase ArrayList esta diseñada para retener colecciones
>   heterogeneas de objetos. Sin embargo, no siempre ofrece el mejor
>   rendimiento."

Y tambien

> "La clase List se ejecuta mejor en la mayoria de casos y es de tipado
>   seguro."

Después el articulo de `List` trata de explicar porqué `List` tiene un mejor rendimiento, pero esta es la parte que no entiendo. Dice literalmente:

> "For a List, if a value type is used for type T, the compiler
>   generates an implementation of the List class specifically for that
>   value type. That means a list element of a List object does not
>   have to be boxed before the element can be used."
>
> "Para una List, si un tipo es usado para el tipo en la lista, el
>   compilador genera una implementación de la clase List
>   especificamente para ese valor de tipo. Eso significa que un elemento
>   listado del objeto List no tiene que estar encajonado antes de poder ser usado."
>
> <sup>*Traducción libre de mi parte</sup>

¿Cúal es realmente la diferencia entre ArrayList y List y por qué dice que List tiene un mejor rendimiento?

---

<sup><sup>P.D.: +10 brownie points al que me diga que debo entender por "boxed" en ese parrafo, que la verdad no pude traducirlo muy bien. Edit: Flxtr se ha llevado los brownie points.</sup></sup>

Comment: *Boxed* se refiere a que antes de que el valor sea guardado en memoria, se le aplica el término "*boxing*", lo cual es el casteo a un `object`, y se aplica "*unboxing*" para poder leer el valor, es decir, de `object` al tipo de dato con el que está referenciado. Talvés una posible traducción sería "encajonado".

Comment: ¿Porqué solo para C#?, no sería mejor generalizar y decir para `.net`.

Comment: @Davlio pues no lo habia pensado, pero si, supongo que para terminos de calidad del sitio y futuros usuarios seria mejor. Lo editare.

Comment: Me ganaron los brownie points :P

Comment: Ok entonces también generalizaré la respuesta para .NET en general

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`ArrayList` es una clase que fue creada desde la versión 1 de C# y el .NET Framework antes que se agregen *Generics*, mientras que `List<T>` es la clase que la  ha reemplazado desde C# 2, .NET Framework 2.0 y VB.NET 2008 (8.0) en adelante.

La diferencia principal es que una instancia de `ArrayList` permite que se agreguen diversos tipos a la colección.

Ejemplo:

C#

```cs
var arrayList = new ArrayList();
arrayList.Add(1); // Puede contener enteros
arrayList.Add("Dos"); // Tambien strings
arrayList.Add(false); // y booleans, etc
```

VB

```vb
Dim arrayList As New ArrayList()
arrayList.Add(1) ' Puede contener enteros
arrayList.Add("Dos") ' Tambien strings
arrayList.Add(False) ' y booleans, etc
```

Mientras que `List<T>` necesita que se defina el tipo de los elementos de la lista al ser instanciado

C#

```cs
var list = new List<int>();
list.Add(1);  // permite agregar enteros
list.Add("Dos"); // error de sintaxis, solo se pueden agregar enteros
```

VB

```vb
Dim list As New List(Of Integer)
list.Add(1) ' permite agregar enteros
list.Add("Dos") ' error de sintaxis, solo se pueden agregar enteros
```

Y acerca del rendimiento la difierencia está en los términos *boxing* y *unboxing*

Boxing se refiere al hecho de envolver un valor de tipo *Reference type* (como `int`, `char`, `float`, `double`, ... entre otros) dentro de una referencia si es que se quiere asignar a una variable o parámetro de tipo `object`. Unboxing se refiere al proceso inverso, es decir a obtener al valor del objeto en una variable de tipo *reference type*.

El problema se encuentra que este proceso de boxing y unboxing ocurre en el caso de `ArrayList` cuando se agrega o obtiene un valor.

Ejemplos:

C#

```cs
var arrayList = new ArrayList();
arrayList.Add(1); // Boxing. Ya que el método Add espera un object
var numero = (int)arrayList[0]; // Unboxing. El indexer devuelve un object que debe ser casteado a `int`
```

VB

```vb
Dim arrayList As New ArrayList()
arrayList.Add(1) ' Boxing. Ya que el método Add espera un object
Dim numero As Integer = arrayList(0) ' Unboxing. El indexer devuelve un object que debe ser casteado a `int`
```

Este proceso toma tiempo de ejecución por lo que es mas lento que el caso genérico.

En el caso genérico con `List<T>` este proceso es inexistente ya que el compilador genera el código para los tipos de datos exactos, (en este caso `int`) y no requiere ningún tiop de conversión.

C#

```cs
var list = new List<int>;
list.Add(1); // No hay boxing puesto que el método espera un int
var numero = list[0]; // No hay cast ni unboxing puesto que el indexer devuelve un int
```

VB

```vb
Dim list As New List(Of Integer)
list.Add(1) ' No hay boxing puesto que el método espera un int
Dim numero As Integer = list(0) ' No hay cast ni unboxing puesto que el indexer devuelve un int
```

Te recomiendo que siempre utilices `List<T>` la verdad no conozco un caso donde convenga usar `ArrayList` ya que si bien no ha sido marcado como obsoleto, en la práctica ya no se usa.

Comment: Muy buena explicación !

Comment: En un momento agrego lo del rendimiento

Comment: Si, me parece que con lo del rendimiento quedara muy bien la respuesta. Estaba a punto de comentarte eso, que si podias añadirlo :D

Answer (score 3):

Básicamente, ArrayList necesita realizar [boxing y unboxing](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/boxing-and-unboxing) cada vez que se guarda/accede a un elemento del array. Esto es así debido a que ArrayList guarda referencias a objetos de tipo object, por tanto necesita realizar la tarea de cast contínuamente.

Por otra parte, List no necesita realizar esa tarea, pues el compilador implementa una lista concreta (¿especializada?) para el tipo T a trabajar. Por eso mismo también es más segura (aunque tampoco asegura la ordenación ojo).

Answer (score 1):

La diferencia se podría entender así:

- Al declarar List le asignas un tipo (String, integer, Booleano) y a medida que agregas elementos es un proceso de asignación de valores de un tipo en específico a un sector de memoria.
- ArrayList en cambio convierte la información que recibe en un objeto completamente nuevo antes de asignarle un espacio en memoria (boxing) y así por cada item del arrayList. Al leerlo no solo debes obtenerlo desde el espacio en RAM, sino que también debe "crearlo" y todas sus propiedades. Lo que consume muchisimos recursos

Answer (score 0):

La clase List(Of T) -T hace referencia a Type (un tipo fijo)- es muy potente. Una de sus mayores cualidades es implementar el interface IEnumerable(Of T), lo que permite el acceso a muchos métodos. Un objeto de esta clase puede ser transformado con facilidad en una array utilizando el método ToArray. Podemos leer la documentación de MSDN sobre esta clase en: [List(Of T) en MSDN](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/98055/c%C3%BAal-es-la-diferencia-entre-list-y-arraylist-en-net)

Una importante ventaja de List(Of T) es que los objetos de esta clase pueden formar parte de consultas en lenguaje LINQ permitiéndonos transformar listas de objetos de un tipo en listas de objetos de otro tipo o en un objeto estadístico como el primer elemento de una lista, el último, el máximo, el mínimo... [LINQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/bb308959.aspx)