# Composición de objetos en C#, no almacena en Arraylist

Tags: c#, poo, arraylist, objeto

Estoy teniendo problemas con un ejercicio en C# y tengo que dar el final de la materia.
Resulta que no estoy pudiendo almacenar en un arraylist los objetos.

Tengo 2 clases a parte de Program, la clase Alumno y Horario.
El problema es que al ingresar el horario que cursa un alumno, no me lo está almacenando en la lista de horarios, por lo que al realizar el foreach me tira siempre el último horario que ingreso.
En el PDF de la materia está explicado de la misma forma que lo estoy haciendo prácticamente, lo leí varias veces pero no encuentro en donde puede estar el problema.

Me podrán ayudar ?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
La clase alumno:

 public class Alumno
    {
        private string nombre;
        private int dni, legajo;
        private ArrayList lista_horarios;
        private string hora;
        private string dia, materia;
        private Horario h;

        public Alumno(){}
        public Alumno(string nombre, int dni, int legajo)
        {
            this.nombre = nombre;
            this.dni = dni;
            this.legajo = legajo;
            lista_horarios = new ArrayList();
        }
        //public Alumno(string hora, string dia,string materia)
        //{
        //    this.hora = hora;
        //    this.dia = dia;
        //    this.materia = materia;
        //}
        public string Hora
        {
            get { return hora; }
            set { value = hora; }
        }
        public string Dia
        {
            get { return dia; }
            set { value = dia; }
        }
        public string Materia
        {
            get { return materia; }
            set {  value = materia;}
        }
        public string Nombre
        {
            get { return nombre; }
            set { nombre = value; }
        }
        public int Dni
        {
            get { return dni; }
            set { dni = value; }
        }
        public int Legajo
        {
            set { legajo = value; }
            get { return legajo; }
        }
        public ArrayList Lista_horarios
        {
            set { lista_horarios = value; }
            get { return lista_horarios; }
        }
        public Horario H
        {
            set { h = value; }
            get { return h; }
        }
        public void inscripcionMateria(string hora,string dia,string materia)
        {
            bool ocupado = false;
            foreach (Horario elem in Lista_horarios) 
            {
                if (dia == elem.Dia && hora == elem.Hora)
                {                     
                        ocupado = true;
                        break;     
                }
            }
            if (ocupado==false)
            {
                H = new Horario(hora, dia, materia);  
           
                lista_horarios.Add(H);
                Console.WriteLine("\nInscripto! \n ");
                foreach (Horario item in Lista_horarios)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Horarios: " + item.Dia+ " "+item.Hora);
                    Console.ReadKey(true);
                }             
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("El horario {0} está ocupado", dia, hora);
                Console.ReadKey(true);
            }
```

La clase Horario.

```
public class Horario
    {
  
        private string hora, dia, n_materia;  
        public Horario(string hora_inicio, string dia_cursada, string n_materia)
        {
            hora = hora_inicio;
            dia = dia_cursada;
            this.n_materia = n_materia;
        }

        public string Hora
        {
            set { hora = value; }
            get { return hora; }
        }
        public string Dia
        {
            set { dia = value; }
            get { return dia; }
        }
        public string N_materia
        {
            set { n_materia = value; }
            get { return n_materia; }
        }
    }
}
internal class Program
    {       
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string horario, dia, materia;
            Alumno a;
            Console.WriteLine("\n Desea inscribir un alumno (s/n)?");
            string s = Console.ReadLine();
            while (s != "n")
            {
                Console.Beep();
                Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el Nombre del alumno: ");
                string name = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el DNI del alumno: ");
                int dni = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el Legajo del alumno");
                int legajo = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                a = new Alumno(name, dni, legajo);
                Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el horario a cursar: ");
                horario= Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el dia a cursar: ");
                dia= Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el nombre de la materia a inscribir: ");
                materia= Console.ReadLine();            

                a.inscripcionMateria(horario,dia,materia);
                
                Console.WriteLine("\n Desea inscribir un alumno (s/n)? ");
                s = Console.ReadLine();
            }

         
        }
```

Comment: [No se recomienda el uso de `ArrayList` y otras colecciones no genéricas](https://github.com/dotnet/platform-compat/blob/master/docs/DE0006.md). En su lugar usa `List<T>` reemplazando T por el tipo de los elementos que tendrá la lista.

Comment: Para poder ayudarte haría falta ver tu bucle principal de ejecución, pero sospecho que el problema es que estas creando un nuevo objeto de la clase `Alumno` cada vez que inscribes a uno, por lo que al recorrer `lista_horarios` solo te aparece el horario del alumno del objeto creado. En lugar de crear `lista_horarios` dentro de tu clase `Alumno`, lo que debes hacer en tu `program` es crear una lista de alumnos, ir añadiendoles ahi a medida que les inscribes y para mostrar los horarios recorrer la lista de alumnos

Comment: Ahí subi el Program, esta abajo de todo. Entiendo que debo crear un nuevo objeto Alumno cada vez que inscribo a uno, y dentro de esa clase deberían estar la lista de horarios que se van agregando.
Nose si estaré en lo correcto..
Muchas gracias por la respuesta..

Comment: En tu clase Alumno, en las propiedades Hora, Dia y Materia estás haciendo **value = hora** en lugar de hora = value y así con las otras dos Dia y Materia.

Answer (score 1):

Entiendo que tú quieres inscribir múltiples alumnos y con múltiples horarios, pare eso en el Main te falta un while para repetir los horarios por alumnos. Que es lo mismo que haces para los alumnos, pero ahora para horarios.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string horario, dia, materia;
    List<Alumno> alumnos = new List<Alumno>(); //Aquí guardaremos los alumnos


    Console.WriteLine("\n Desea inscribir un alumno (s/n)?");
    string s = Console.ReadLine()!;
    while (s.ToLower() != "n")
    {

        Console.Beep();
        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el Nombre del alumno: ");
        string name = Console.ReadLine()!;
        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el DNI del alumno: ");
        int dni = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()!);
        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el Legajo del alumno");
        int legajo = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()!);
        Alumno a = new Alumno(name, dni, legajo);


        Console.WriteLine("\n Desea ingresar un horario (s/n)?");
        string s2 = Console.ReadLine()!;
        while (s2.ToLower() != "n") //hacemos una iteración por horario
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el horario a cursar: ");


            horario = Console.ReadLine()!;
            Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el dia a cursar: ");
            dia = Console.ReadLine()!;
            Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el nombre de la materia a inscribir: ");
            materia = Console.ReadLine()!;

            a.InscribirMateria(horario, dia, materia);

            Console.WriteLine("\n Desea ingresar un horario (s/n)?");
            s2 = Console.ReadLine()!;
        }

        alumnos.Add(a);   

        Console.WriteLine("\n Desea inscribir un alumno (s/n)? ");
        s = Console.ReadLine()!;


    }

    //Mostrar todos los alumnos
    foreach(Alumno alumno in alumnos)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Nombre: " + alumno.Nombre);
        Console.WriteLine("Dni: " + alumno.Dni);
        Console.WriteLine("Legajo: " + alumno.Legajo);
        alumno.ImprimirHorarios();
    }
}
```

---

Permíteme unos tips ya que tu código tiene mucho olor a java.

1. En C# tenemos varios tipos de listas, el más común es List, casi no se ocupa ArrayList, más información acá [¿Cúal es la diferencia entre List y ArrayList en .NET?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/98055/301324)
2. Tus propiedades las declaras de esta manera:

```
public string Hora
{
   set { hora = value; }
   get { return hora; }
}
```

Esto no es necesario en C#, salvo que requieras implementar alguna lógica dentro del `Set` o el `Get`, lo cual no es tu caso. Por lo que tu solo tienes que colocar:

```
public string Hora { get; set; }
```

Es más corto y no es necesario crear una variable auxiliar para almacenar el valor de la propiedad

3. Tu función `inscripcionMateria` puede (y debe) separarse en otras funciones, también recomiendo cambiar el nombre a un verbo como `InscribirMateria`

Dejo el código completo con los cambios propuestos:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string horario, dia, materia;
    List<Alumno> alumnos = new List<Alumno>();


    Console.WriteLine("\n Desea inscribir un alumno (s/n)?");
    string s = Console.ReadLine()!;
    while (s.ToLower() != "n")
    {

        Console.Beep();
        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el Nombre del alumno: ");
        string name = Console.ReadLine()!;
        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el DNI del alumno: ");
        int dni = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()!);
        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el Legajo del alumno");
        int legajo = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()!);
        Alumno a = new Alumno(name, dni, legajo);


        Console.WriteLine("\n Desea ingresar un horario (s/n)?");
        string s2 = Console.ReadLine()!;
        while (s2.ToLower() != "n")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el horario a cursar: ");


            horario = Console.ReadLine()!;
            Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el dia a cursar: ");
            dia = Console.ReadLine()!;
            Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el nombre de la materia a inscribir: ");
            materia = Console.ReadLine()!;

            a.InscribirMateria(horario, dia, materia);

            Console.WriteLine("\n Desea ingresar un horario (s/n)?");
            s2 = Console.ReadLine()!;
        }

        alumnos.Add(a);   

        Console.WriteLine("\n Desea inscribir un alumno (s/n)? ");
        s = Console.ReadLine()!;


    }

    //Mostrar todos los alumnos
    foreach(Alumno alumno in alumnos)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Nombre: " + alumno.Nombre);
        Console.WriteLine("Dni: " + alumno.Dni);
        Console.WriteLine("Legajo: " + alumno.Legajo);
        alumno.ImprimirHorarios();
    }
}
    

public class Horario
{
    public Horario(string hora_inicio, string dia_cursada, string n_materia)
    {
        Hora = hora_inicio;
        Dia = dia_cursada;
        this.N_materia = n_materia;
    }

    public string Hora { get;set; }
    public string Dia { get; set; }
    public string N_materia { get; set; }
}
public class Alumno
{
    public Alumno(string nombre, int dni, int legajo)
    {
        this.Nombre = nombre;
        this.Dni = dni;
        this.Legajo = legajo;
        Lista_horarios = new List<Horario>();
    }
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public int Dni { get; set; }
    public int Legajo { get; set; }
    public List<Horario> Lista_horarios { get; set; }
    
    private bool isDiaOcupado(string dia, string hora)
    {
        foreach (Horario elem in Lista_horarios)
        {
            if (dia == elem.Dia && hora == elem.Hora)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void ImprimirHorarios()
    {
        foreach (Horario item in Lista_horarios)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Horarios: " + item.Dia + " " + item.Hora);
        }
    }

    public void InscribirMateria(string hora, string dia, string materia)
    {
        if (isDiaOcupado(dia, hora))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("El horario {0} está ocupado", dia, hora);
            Console.ReadKey(true);
            return;
        }

        Lista_horarios.Add(new Horario(hora, dia, materia));
        Console.WriteLine("\nInscripto! \n ");
        ImprimirHorarios();

    }
}
```

Comment: Ahi pude!!!
Muchísimas Gracias!!! era eso nomas... no lo puedo creer!!