# Llenar una lista de objetos en C#

Tags: lista

Hola deseo llenar una lista con objetos luego de consultar a una bd,

```
List<EUbigeo> lista = new List<EUbigeo>();
        String query = "select * from ubigeo where estado='A'";
        comando.Connection = conexion.openConexion();
        comando.CommandText = query;
        leer = comando.ExecuteReader();
        EUbigeo ubigeo = new EUbigeo();
        try {

             while(leer.Read())
            {

                ubigeo.Departamento = Convert.ToString(leer[0]);
                ubigeo.Provincia = Convert.ToString(leer[1]);
                ubigeo.Distrito = Convert.ToString(leer[2]);
                ubigeo.Nombre= Convert.ToString(leer[3]);
                ubigeo.Estado = Convert.ToChar(leer[4]);
                lista.Add(ubigeo); 
                }

         }  
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " + e.Message);
        }
        return lista;
```

ahora resulta, que la lista de objetos esta lleno pero de un mismo objeto, es decir si el ultimo objeto es: ubigeo[departamento5, provincia5, distrito5, A]... la lista completa esta llena de ese mismo objeto.

Ya se ha probado de la siguiente forma con el mismo resultado

```
String query = "select * from ubigeo where estado='A'";
        comando.Connection = conexion.openConexion();
        comando.CommandText = query;
        leer = comando.ExecuteReader();  
        try {

            while (leer.Read())
            {

                lista.Add(new EUbigeo()
                {
                    Departamento = Convert.ToString(leer[0]),
                    Provincia = Convert.ToString(leer[1]),
                    Distrito = Convert.ToString(leer[2]),
                    Nombre = Convert.ToString(leer[3]),
                    Estado = Convert.ToChar(leer[4])

                });
            }
         }  
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " + e.Message);
        }
        return lista;
```

---

Me respondo a mi mismo, con una pregunta:
Mi clase inicialmente estuvo estructurado asi (esta comentado), de esa forma generaba que la lista se llenara con el mismo objeto.

```
public class EUbigeo
{
    //private static String _departamento;
    //private static String _provincia;
    //private static String _distrito;
    //private static String _nombre;
    //private static char _estado;

    //public String Departamento
    //{
    //    get { return _departamento; }
    //    set { _departamento = value; }
    //}
```

y se cambio de la siguiente forma, y funciona ok:

```
    public String Departamento { get; set; }
    public String Provincia { get; set; }
    public String Distrito { get; set; }
    public String Nombre { get; set; }
```

Que diferencia hay en las declaraciones?.. por ser declaradas Static?

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/98036/cómo-agregar-elementos-a-un-array-en-c, en esta respuesta hable de lo mismo y llega,os a una conclusión, revisa por favor

Answer (score 3):

Tu problema esta aqui:

```
EUbigeo ubigeo = new EUbigeo();
try {
    while(leer.Read())
    {
        ...
        lista.Add(ubigeo); 
    }
...
```

Has creado un objeto `ubigeo` fuera del ciclo, por lo que cada vez que se agrege a la lista, estaras agregando ese mismo objeto, pero con la informacion actualizada.
La razon por la que siempre tiene la misma informacion, es que se almacena una referencia al objeto cada vez que lo agregaste a la lista, y no un objeto nuevo.

Metiendolo dentro del ciclo deberia de corregirse tu problema:

```
try {
    while(leer.Read())
    {
        EUbigeo ubigeo = new EUbigeo();
        ...
        lista.Add(ubigeo); 
    }
...
```

Comment: Inicialmente mi code estuvo asi con el objeto ubigeo dentro del ciclo, al ver que se llenaba todo con el ultimo objeto recorrido, lo saque para probar.

Comment: Prueba agregarlo de vuelta dentro del while, solo por diversion ;P

Answer (score 0):

Eso es por que lo estas llenando con la misma instancia del objeto, estas usando la misma posición en memoria.

usa

```
lista.Add(new EUbigeo(){
          Departamento = Convert.ToString(leer[0]),
          Provincia = Convert.ToString(leer[1]),Convert.ToString(leer[2]),
          Nombre= Convert.ToString(leer[3]),Estado = Convert.ToChar(leer[4])});
```

Comment: Aun asi, sigue llenando con el ultimo valor de la consulta